# How to get the connection URL parameters using socket.io

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I have a client script that makes calls to this server

```
var _websocket = new WebSocket(ws://localhost:3000/<param>, ["ocpp1.6", "ocpp1.5"]);
```

I want to get the message sent from the client using this socket.io server but I haven't found a way to connect properly and get the parameter.

```
import { Server } from 'socket.io'

const io = new Server(3000)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Cliente conectado:', socket.id)

  console.log(socket.handshake.url)
})
```

Excuse my English, I am not a native speaker.

I saw that there is something called a namespace in socket.io, but they must be defined to connect to that namespace, but what I want is to get the parameter after the slash, which is variable since it is a connection identifier.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your quesiton, but have you considered using plain websockets? Easy to do it with `ws`